# Is the word 'current' applicable to the past?

Tags: word-usage, word-meaning

If I talk about past events, can I use the word 'current' meaning "the one that was ongoing back then"? For instance

> In March 2017, supplies were cut off due to the fact that the company failed to pay off its debts and to make a prepayment for the **current** month (i.e. March 2017).

Comment: I think I would change that to "a prepayment for that month."

Comment: It doesn't work. It's certainly not clear that **current** here refers to March. I agree with Chaim.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, because it creates ambiguity and makes the sentence difficult to understand. Changing to "a prepayment for *that month*" as Chaim suggests in the comments is sensible.

Current means now, or contemporary, or present. If I read your example sentence in an online article, I would initially think the company failed to may the prepayment at the time the article was written, which of course doesn't make sense.

Comment: You can "force" *current* to apply to the past by saying "then-current" - e.g. "He was told to pay the then-current invoice," but since you mention a date, you should definitely say *that* to link it back to the month you said over trying to use *current*.